# Is there an Air Video app, but for photos?

Tags: ipad, applications, photos

I was wondering if there is an app for the iPad in order to see photos that are shared in a Windows/Mac folder.

I went to Australia and took over 12000 photos, now I want to take a close look at all of them without without importing all to iTunes (so it does not fill up space on my iPad).

Something that I could check, mark in order to move/copy to a diff folder so I can edit them later.

For iPhone there is the [WiFi Photo Viewer](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wifi-photo-viewer/id395876857?mt=8) but I can't find one for iPad.

Answer (score 2):

I developed [ImageBank for iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imagebank/id382641857?mt=8) to do exactly this - streams photos from your PC/Mac to your iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch.  It's universal so it works natively on the iPad, and it even works over 3G.

There's a free version too if you want to try it out:
[ImageBank Lite](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imagebank-lite/id385895348?mt=8)

It's only US $0.99 to buy or upgrade from the free version.

Comment: I'll give it a try and will upload a review on itunes after... thxs for sharing

Comment: ImageBank is great. Is there any way to run the ImageBank server on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

StreamToMe is far better than Air Video in many ways. One prime example is it's ability to remotely view photos. It will work with files stored anywhere or even browse your iPhoto library It also supports audio only files and portrait orientation playback while Air Video does not. It's a universal app that runs on iPhones too and the server app runs on Mac or PC. Price - $2.99.

The interface is nicer and there's even a recent history for convenience. It has always perplexed me why AirVideo is more popular.

Alternatively, there's another great app you may wanna look at when you get some time called HereFileFile. It does not have an iPad optimized version yet, but they are in fact working on one as we speak. It looks very promising. However, the iPhone version is very nice. It's fairly similar in concept to these other two apps, but there are differences which I won't go into here.

Comment: because, if you read the comments, only the latest version is stable... plenty of glitches in StreamToMe prior to the latest version, where AirVideo was always very stable. And, I most say that AirVideo spend more in marketing :)

Answer (score 1):

while it requires a jailbreak, I was really impressed after installing [AirServer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tv7BfMIikvc&feature=player_embedded) yesterday - I can run the server on my iPad and use my iPhoto to stream photos over AirPlay - really really awesome when you're not nearby a TV and if you are, you've got the reverse - a mini AppleTV in your pocket with your iPad as a beautiful remote for content!

Comment: For this I would take AirPlay on the new iOS5 witch I currently use in my iPad2, iPhone4 and Apple TV2G.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>On the link you provide, it is marked as compatible with iPad. What's the issue? Moreover, it seems they're running a christmas sale :)</strike>

---

Apart my silly remark above (which clearly deserved votes down. Probably let too many neurons in the end of year festivities... :-/) there is an [Air Photo HD app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-photo-hd/id363707637?mt=8). It seems to be a browser of your iPhoto library over the air. Are you using iPhoto? If so, it could be a solution. Though, from the screenshots, I don't know if you can mark them as accepted/rejected.

Otherwise, depending on the total size of your photos folder, Dropbox or similar services could be used, as what you'll do on the iPad will then be sync'ed automatically in the cloud (Dropbox free account is 2GB)

Comment: Compatible with iPad, as all apps are. It is not, however, optimized for iPad. No larger resolution photos, no taking advantage of the additional space on the iPad, it's just the app running in emulation mode, with the 1x/2x display setting.

Comment: when it says "Compatible" it means that's will run on the iPad in `iPhone` mode with the `1x` and `2x` buttons, not what I'm after

Comment: it doesn't have good reviews and their support website it doesn't even have the app, I would run away from this.

Answer (score 0):

ImageBank for iPhone/iPad does the trick for me!

Comment: it has really bad reviews :(

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you were looking for, but if you had the time/bandwidth, you could upload the 12,000 photos to [Flickr](http://flickr.com). Then you would have many more options for viewing/sharing. You could view the photos via Safari on the iPad or download one of the many applications which support viewing a Flickr feed.

Again, not ideal. Food for thought.

Good luck!

Comment: I have a Flickr Pro account and that is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a dedicated app (and it sure seems like something at least 20 people would have implemented by now) you could go old school and use safari and web sharing.

I have used the export to web page and export to slide show functionality of iPhoto/Aperture to save a html folder to the ~/Sites folder.

Then it's simple to turn on web sharing and use mobile safari to browse the thumbnail pages or just click through the main images as a slide show.

You can also export the slide show and a quicktime movie can be dumped if you would prefer better transitions and full screen with less tapping to navigate.

I might try out [PixelSync](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pixelsync/id409409239?mt=8) next time I need to rate and do heavier editing from the couch or by handing the iPad to a client. Again - this won't be good unless you want your photos in a managed database as it won't work with just a folder of files.

And way out in "the OP didn't even ask this" land is a suggestion to check out [PhotoMechanic](http://www.camerabits.com/site/index.html) - it stores all images in a folder but is optimized for extremely rapid optimized rating of many photos. There isn't an iPad/iPhoto link, but I've seen professionals blitz through 4.5k photos at the end of a major marathon and cull that first to 500 and then a second pass to the 35 images that make the day's news media picks for press use. With 12k images you might need a great tool on the computer to narrow down things before you move them to iOS land.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite following the reasoning behind chasing for an iOS app for aide in your sorting process. No matter what app you find, importing to your Mac/PC and using one of many available applications will allow far greater ease and efficiency to go through such a massive bulk of images. Why not import and then sort them in an Aperture library? Your data doesn't get locked in, you can rate, edit, sort, and delete photos, and you can get a 30-day trial.

Comment: You're kidding right? I don't know about your library but I already pass 1Tb of photos a long time ago!

Comment: That'd normally fall under the idea of 'deleting' photos.

Comment: I'm not going to delete good photos! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you've willing to put the photos in iPhoto, we've just released an app that will stream them to your iPad over your home Wi-Fi network: AirPics.

http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/airpics/id475202862?mt=8

It does not support flagging photos, but is good for streaming large albums (I've tested it with more than 3000 photos in a single album on my iPad 2 without issue).

Comment: just like AirPlay, we should simply use a shared folder, **windows or mac**, it's easy to develop a small app that would use **Bounjour** to connect folder with the iPad. ...just like AirVideo.